# How to prevent un-necessary GCM messages?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have integrated my application with the GCM. Setup the third party server which checks whether an update needed for a device, if yes, it sends the GCM as a tickle telling the mobile application to contact the server for the fresh data.

My android application has authentication module with logon/logoff actions. And I only intend the server data synch (and so as the GCM messages) as long as user's current session is active.

But, as the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) suggests, the Android application on an device doesn't need to be running to receive messages. The system will wake up the Android application via Intent broadcast when the message arrives.

My question is, how do I prevent the GCM messages when user is logged off or the application is shutdown?

Which one of the following seems better? can you suggest any other approach?

**Option A:**

My android application to register for the GCM once the user is successfully logged on and un-register from the GCM once the user is logged off. This will enforce my third party server to only send the GCM messages when the registration id is available. But is the register/un-register so frequently is a recommended practice?

**Option B:**

Let the android application receive the messages even during logged off or shutdown state, but the application does not react on them (i.e. just ignore them). Is this a recommended practice? Would it cost any penalty in terms of performance? Would the user notice un-necessary (annoying) wakeups of the android application?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As per my suggestion the second one is the better option what you can do whatever push message you are getting from server update it in a preference file (only the last one or imp one) and while user logged in notify him/her.

Comment: When user logs on it will always get the fresh data so I think I would not need to store the latest message to preference file (as the message just has to say that refresh the data, and that anyway is happening on logon). My questions are, Is this a recommended practice? Would it cost any penalty in terms of performance? Would the user notice un-necessary (annoying) wakeups of the android application?

Comment: no its not a performance issue your device will not wake up unnecessarily while getting push messages its a feature of GCM thas why we are giving a permission of wake_lock in manifest while using GCM.

Comment: @Wayofhope one more thing you can implement if it is feasible for you, just hit a web service to ask for latest update to server while logged on or starting the application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, on logon I hit the web service and load the latest data. However, the developer tutorial suggests the first option if application has logoff feature http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg